# Does Excel VBA have a limit on the number of SQL Inserts it will write?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to insert rows into SQl Server. When I do a small test of about 5 records it works as expected and the new data is inserted. However when I run a full test (100,000 + records) the code runs but no records are inserted. If I copy the `INSERT` statements into SSMS and execute them all 100,000+ insert with no errors. Am I going over some sort of limit that VBA has?  Below is the code I am currently working with.

```vb
Public Sub OpenConn()
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn
.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=USHDEVEVRSTDB\SDEVOLTP4;Initial 
Catalog=DataManagement;Integrated Security=SSPI;": .Open
End With
End Sub

Public Sub DisposeConn()
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub WriteData()
With Application
.DisplayAlerts = True: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False
End With
Dim strSQL As String
Dim wkbTarget As Workbook
Dim Comments As String
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Set wkbTarget = ThisWorkbook

On Error GoTo Dispose
Call OpenConn
'SELECT THE RANGE ON THE SQLINSTERTSTRINGS SHEET TO SET AS THE COMMENTS AND INSERT THEM
Sheets("SQLInsertStrings").Activate
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)
For Each row In rng.Rows
    strSQL = row

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Execute
    End With
    strSQL = ""
Next row

'CLOSE SUB
Dispose:
    Call DisposeConn
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Update Complete", vbInformation, "Confimation Message"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not inserting into SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio); SSMS in just an IDE (for SQL Server). It's database hosted in a SQL Server instance you are `INSERT`ing data into.

Comment: I don't know of any limit. It's just a loop and it's executed, like all things in VBA, as a single thread (in series). I would remove that `On Error Goto Dispose` and rerun your 100k and see what errors are thrown.

Comment: Thank you both for the input.  I found the error was RunTime Error 6 Overflow.  Changed the Lastrow variable to Long and that seems to have got everything going now.

Comment: Fix your error handling first. Had that error been exposed, you would have immediately known what the problem was.